# Apache CXF Soap Client in Wildlfy

Tags: apache, soap, jboss, client, cxf

I am trying to build a SOAP Client inside a wildfly JEE App. I am using CXF directly. I generate the SOAP Client by using wsdl2java and use the Client this way:

```
ServicePortTypeV1 servicePortV1 = new ServiceV1().getServicePortV1();
```

Afterwards I am trying to call a method which doesn't work

In the end I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit.createConnection(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:104)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit.setupConnection(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:117)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.prepare(HTTPConduit.java:497)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:46)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:514)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:423)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:324)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:277)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:13
```

It seems like the address is null. But I can't tell why? Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Could you share the WSDL?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. First we implemented this on a tomcat. The wsdl was "searched" by classpath relative path, which is allowed in tomcat but not in wildfly. I changed it by using the resource to open the URL for the wsdl.